# How to obtain bean from context?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, websecurity

I have two services A and B, and A has in its pom file the dependency from B.

In service B I am creating a bean of a class named `ClassB`, and in service A I have a class called `ClassA` that receives in the constructor as parameter an instance of the `ClassB` from the other service.

Even I specify in the import section that is from the other service when I run both services I get the error:

> Error creating bean with name 'classA' defined in file
>   [something/ClassA.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
>   constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'something.something.something.something.something.ClassB' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations: {}

I don't know how to specify to autowire the class with the bean of the other service.

```
package .....;

import something.something.something.something.something.ClassB;

public class ClassA {

    private ClassB classB;

    @Autowired
    public ClassA(ClassB classB) {
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    //More methods not relevant

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try annotating ClassA and ClassB with @Component

Comment: you can also inside classA use the  ApplicationContext to get classB

Answer (score 0):

Inn your `@Configuration` class create a a method anotated with `@Bean` that returns the ClassB instance named `classB` as below

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfigClass {

    ...
    .
    .
    @Bean
    public ClassB classB() {
        return new ClassB();
    }
    .
    .
    ...
}
```